# Why isn't cv2.resize() working when I convert my python code to an executable (.exe)

Tags: python, opencv, resize, exe, executable

I am using the code below to resize an image. This code works great when I run it using any IDE, but is causing issues when I run as an executable.

```
cv2.resize(img,(320,240))
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error when I convert my code to an executable (.exe) and press run.

> img = cv2.resize(img, (320,240))
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

What is causing this error to occur?

Comment: How are you reading your input image?

Comment: Have you checked `img` not to be empty? By the way...Try exception handling (e.g. Try Except). I think it could be helpful.

Comment: imread has a return value. I think the return value will be zero if it does not open or cannot find the image. As a quick and dirty, you can print the retval and see if it looks good. Once you debug the code you can delete or comment out your print statements.